# Creating a popup with responsive styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, popup

I'm trying to create a popup with 2 inner divs with responsive sizing.

I thought I could achieve this by setting their `width` and `height` as percentages of the parent div but it doesn't seem to work. If you resize your browser window, the leftArea div in my jsfiddle falls out of the popup div.

How can I fix this?

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80351/2a412w4n/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` property to set the padding and border inner the box width.

Check more docs here: [box-sizing - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```css
body {
   background-color: black;
}

.popup {
   position: absolute;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 80vw;
   height: 10vh;
   left: 0%;
   right: 0%;
   top: 50%;
   display: block;
   background-color: orange;
   border: 2px solid white;
   border-radius: 15px;
}

.leftArea {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
   width: 85%;
   height: 98%;
   margin: 0px;
   background-color: red;
   border-radius: 14px 0px 0px 14px; 
   border: 0px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
   box-sizing: border-box; /* Use this property to set the padding inner */
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: left;
  
}

.rightArea {
   position: relative;
   float: right;
   width: 12.25%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: #123456;
   margin: 0px;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 0px 14px 14px 0px; 
   border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup">
   <div class="leftArea"></div>
   <div class="rightArea"></div>
</div>
```